# How to generate same random string from two numbers even if we swap them?

Tags: php

I am looking for following logic in PHP:

1. First number 491
2. Second number 784

Goal to generate a common encrypted string from these two numbers, even if we reverse them:

```
    <?php                
          function common_string_generator($num1, $num2) {
                  return enc_string_generator($num1, $num2);
          }
          # first 
          $room_one = common_string_generator(491, 784);

          # second
          $room_two = common_string_generator(784, 491);
          if($room_one===$room_two) {
                print "Success";
          } else {
                print "Failure";
          }
    ?>

    #Am here: 
    <?php 
            ........
            $n1 = md5($num1, $num2);
            $n2 = md5(num2, num1);
            ........
    ?>
```

3. I am not able to fix the order of both numbers they got reverse since both numbers are Ids of users going into private chat room.
4. The both ids are unique, and the encrypted string from these will be unique, I want that unique encrypted string to become the id of their chat room.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could arbitrarily decide to always use the smaller number as the first parameter and the larger one as the second:

```
function common_string_generator($num1, $num2) {
    $param1 = min($num1, num2);
    $param2 = max($num1, num2);
    return enc_string_generator($param1, $param2);
}
```